# adding data to excel pivot table, that has been added to a data model

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table

in my excel file I have 2 sheets, pivot table and data sheet. The pivot table has been added to the data model.

[picture of my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3bYA.png)

When I try to change the data sheet's data using python it corrupts the file and breaks the pivot table. is there possible way to update the pivot tables data without breaking it?

When I don't add the pivot table to the data model this code works just fine, but when it's added this code breaks the table.

```
import pandas as pd

# initial data that is used to make the pivot table in the excel file
data = {
    'Country': ['USA', 'Canada'],
    'Population': [328_200_000, 37_590_000],
    'Capital': ['Washington D.C.', 'Ottawa']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# data to replace the initial data
data2 = {
    'Country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'UK', 'Australia', 'Finland'],
    'Population': [328_200_000, 37_590_000, 66_650_000, 25_360_000, 5_000_000],
    'Capital': ['Washington D.C.', 'Ottawa', 'London', 'Canberra', 'Helsinki']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Append new data to the existing data and write it to the Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter('Excel.xlsx', mode='a', engine='openpyxl', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    print("open excel")

    # Write the merged data to the sheet
    print("Data")
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Data', index=False, startrow=0)
```

Somehow the adding of the data model causes the pivot table to break every time something is added. I want to find a way to add data to it without corrupting the file.